# Numpy slicing multiple dimensions by lists

Tags: numpy

Given a matrix, say

```
>>> a=np.arange(25).reshape(5,-1)
```

Can I achieve

```
>>> idx=[1,3]
>>> a[idx][:,idx]
array([[ 6,  8],
       [16, 18]])
```

without having to slice *a* twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`broadcast` idx` against itself:

```
In [118]: a=np.arange(25).reshape(5,-1)
In [119]: i,j=np.ix_([1,3],[1,3])
In [120]: i,j
Out[120]: 
(array([[1],
        [3]]),
 array([[1, 3]]))
In [121]: a[i,j]
Out[121]: 
array([[ 6,  8],
       [16, 18]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly like I want it to.